# How to pass address of C++ object to C

Tags: c++, c, object, garbage-collection, destroy

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and C++11. I want to pass the address of a C++ object back to C. The C code will treat it as a opaque handle; C will never reference it. The only use will be to pass it back to C++ where it will again be used as a pointer to object.

I'm finding that if I create the object in C++ and pass it back to C, the object will be destroyed because it goes out of scope. As a work around, I created a global variable to hold the object so it won't be destroyed upon returning to C. What is the best practice? Should I use a ref-counted pointer type such as `shared_ptr`? How? I don't like the idea of casting to `size_t` or such.

The following is an attempt to demonstrate the question. Code won't work.

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall SwbHttpListenW(const wchar_t *route, SwbHttpListen **listener)
{
    *listener = &SwbHttpListen(route); // new will work but how about without new?
}
```

[Edited the code to re-ask for a solution not using `new`.]

Comment: If you're allocating the object using `new`, the object does not go out of scope and thus does not get destroyed... ever (unless you're calling `delete` on it later). (Your pointer to it goes out of scope, but other than the potential for a memory leak if you didn't keep a copy of it elsewhere, that's not a factor.) This makes your question hard to understand.

Comment: Arg. I unwittingly stumbled upon the answer and didn't realize it. I simply had to realize that my rewrite using `new`solved the problem. Regardless, I don't know the answer if without new. I'm editing the question to reflect that.

Comment: If your scope is going to close, then creating the object outside of that scope is the solution, and doing it using `new` is generally the way to apply it.

Comment: Anyone have an answer without new? Seems like this can be solved using shared_ptr or such.

Comment: Your choices of where an object lives are: in a block of code (which can have scope issues), as a global variable, or dynamically allocated, or within another object (that has the same options). It doesn't matter what kind of pointer you have, if the object itself is destroyed then the pointer is no longer valid. The only alternative is to copy the object, rather than a pointer to it.

Comment: I can't help thinking that a ref counted pointer, such as shared_ptr, can be used to control gc.

Comment: Why is this question tagged garbage-collection?  Are you using the non-standard C++ extensions?

Comment: @BSalita even if you have GC (C++ doesn't have it, you would have to add it to your system), GC doesn't operate on automatically allocated items (items which are not allocated via `new`).

Comment: Do I understand this correctly. The issue is that possibly all C++ compilers are designed to auto allocate plain old objects on a stack. When the method goes out of scope, the stack is reset. A smart pointer won't help. Question: Does C++ 11 specify that the object must be destroyed when going out of scope or is this an implementation detail? I'm afraid I was thinking that C++ objects were ref counted like COM objects and didn't necessarily have to go out of scope. Is there are C++ implementation that handles objects like COM?

Answer (score 2):

How about heap allocating the C++ object using the *new* operator, and getting its address by using the ampersand (*&*) operator? By heap allocating the object, you ensure it will never be deleted until you actually use the *delete* operator on it, and the address could be stored/passed as an int.

A simple example:

```
int main() {

    Person *a = new Person("Paul");
    doSomething(a); //Passes the memory address of a to the function doSomething



    //...and once you're finished using the object, you have to:
    delete a;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code is not correct. `new Person("Paul")` will return a `Person*`. There is no need to take the address of `a` as it's already a pointer.

Comment: But when you heap allocate using new, what you get back from new is already the address of the object so you don't need to use &...

Comment: Woah, it's getting too late for me. Sorry about the bad code -- time to go to bed.

Answer (score 1):

It's always going to be messy when you do this sort of thing, how you handle it really depends upon what you want the lifetime of your c++ object to be and, to a lesser extent, how you are going to get rid of it in the end. But clearly the c++ has to do any destruction, you cannot get the c to do that.

This sort of thing is an example of when it is not necessarily A Bad Thing to have global objects - though of course that means you cannot get rid of it freely. Alternatively, you could create it dynamically using new but you then will need an arrangement between the c and the c++ so that it gets deleted at the right time - you might end up with a global object pointer or maybe the c could pass the pointer back to get it destroyed - that would be the nicest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Some trouble may be if some automated Garbage Collector are in use (it may be in C++). `std::declare_reachable` , `std::undeclare_reachable` may help.
Else the trouble really doesn't concern passing a pointer to C. And you need to develop some way to achieve a proper pointers to valid objects at the places where necessary... :-)